# Cómo puedo hacer el redirect 301 en github pages?

Tags: javascript

Intenté esto con javascript pero no me funciona bien:

```
<script>
  var host = "edonrosa6.github.io";
  if ((host == window.location.host) && (window.location.protocol != "https:"))
  window.location.protocol = "https:";
</script>
```

Comment: y por que no lo rediriges a la ruta?? `windows.location.href = "https://edonrosa6.github.io"`

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas mayor chance de obtener una respuesta. Decir "no me funciona" no es de mucha ayuda, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/479313/edit) tu pregunta describiendo mejor el problema que presentas